# Custom CIFilter - a CIColorCube - does not change the UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimage, core-image

I have made a custom CIColorCube filter, to turn an image in predetermined shades of gray (evenly spaced, black and white included) into a coloured image, with each shade turned into a different hue.
The problem is - it either does not give any output or gives back the image completely unchanged.
Here's the code of the filter:

```
class GreyToColoutrsFilterMaker{
static let FilterHaver = GreyToColoutrsFilterMaker()
let filter: CIFilter?
private init() {
    let size = Constants.SHADES_COUNT
    var cubeRGB = [Float]()
    for _ in 0 ..< size {
        for _ in 0 ..< size {
            for x in 0 ..< size {
                let red = CGFloat(x) / CGFloat(size-1)
                
                let hue = (1 - red) * 240 / 360
                let destColor = UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: 1, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
                let colorParts = destColor.rgba
                cubeRGB.append(Float(colorParts.red))
                cubeRGB.append(Float(colorParts.green))
                cubeRGB.append(Float(colorParts.blue))
                cubeRGB.append(Float(colorParts.alpha))
            }
        }
    }
    let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: cubeRGB) { Data($0) }
    filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorCube", parameters: ["inputCubeDimension": size, "inputCubeData": data])
}
```

And here's how I use it on the UIImage img:

```
if let filter = GreyToColoutrsFilterMaker.FilterHaver.filter{
            let ciImg = CIImage(image: img)
            filter.setDefaults()
            filter.setValue(ciImg, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
            if let filteredImageData = filter.outputImage{
                let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
                if let filteredImageRef =   ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent){
                    img = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef)
                }
            }
        }
```

If the line "filter.setDefaults()" is removed, then the code inside "if let filteredImageData = filter.outputImage" does not execute, showing that the filter did not return any data. But if the line is used, then the filter does not change the image in any way.

Comment: Maybe `filter.setDefaults()` sets some property that is required, and which you are not setting, but some other properties are not what you need. Compare the filter with and without `filter.setDefaults()` object property by property and see what the difference is.

Comment: All it did was confirm that filter.setDefaults() does indeed mess the filter up by overriding the cube's data. But the only properties special to this particular filter over other CIFilter seems to be CubeData and CubeDimention - both of which are set when creating the filter singleton.

Comment: Just found out that data is shown as having the size of only 8 bytes, despite the input having 864 floats. Is this a sign of initing the data wrong or is it how it's supposed to be because pointers?

Comment: ah, so try this `cubeRGB.withUnsafeBufferPointer { Data(buffer: $0) } as Data` instead of `withUnsafeBytes(of: cubeRGB) { Data($0) }`

Comment: Duplicate question then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the initing of data to:

```
let data = cubeRGB.withUnsafeBufferPointer{ Data(buffer: $0) }
```

After that, the filter started to work without setting defaults.